# Add a new attribute to existing json object in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an object like this

```
==================records=========={ Id: 5114a3c21203e0d811000088,
  userId: 'test',
  sUserId: test,
  userName: 'test',
  url: 'test',
  Title: 'test'
}
```

I need to add a new field **Name : 'test'** to the above record, I tried giving records.Name = name, it didn't work.

Helps please

Thanks,
Prats

Comment: is this record comes from a db, like mongodb, using mongoose?

Comment: @balaz: yes it came from mongoose, records.set('Name', 'test') worked for me

Comment: when do you check the value of this db record? after saving to the db? I'm asking this, because maybe if the field what you want is not in the Schema, mongoose won't save it to the database, you should add it to the schema, or call `markModified`. please provide more code as @neelsg suggested.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those finding this problem, OP mentioned in a comment below the original question that the solution for this problem is:

```
records.set('Name', 'test')
```

This adds a new attribute called `Name` having value `test`.

Comment: how do i add the new attribute to a json object i have stored in a mysql table column? now ` "1":{"lastname":"blah","firstname":"R.A.","function":"General Manager","email":"test@hotmail.com","barcode":"33432799181"} ` and i like `"1":{"lastname":"blah","firstname":"R.A.","function":"General Manager","email":"test@hotmail.com","barcode":"33432799181", "visited":"0"}`

Answer (score 56):

I am assuming you are trying to add a property to a returned Mongoose Document to reuse it somewhere else. Documents returned by Mongoose are not JSON objects directly, you'll need to convert them to an object to add properties to them. The following should work:

```
//... record is a mongoose Document
var r = record.toObject();
r.Name = 'test';
console.log("Record ",r);
```

Comment: Doesn't look like it is deprecated http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject,

Comment: this only works if you set `toObject: {}` or `toJSON: {}` in your schema options, but yeah this still works just fine

Answer (score 11):

Just use,

```
var convertedJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mongooseReturnedDocument);
```

and Then,

```
convertedJSON.newProperty = 'Hello!'
```

'Hello!' can be anything, a number, a object or JSON Object Literal.

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 6):

I experienced a similar problem, and hope that my hours of existential frustration help others in the same situation. My inclination was to believe that documents returned via Mongoose are read-only. This is actually not true.

However, you cannot assign a property to your document that is not also in your Schema.

So, unless your schema has the following:

```
{
    Name: {String}
}
```

you will be constantly frustrated by trying to assign Name to your document.

Now, there are workarounds in the answers above that also worked for me, but they do not get to the root of the problem:

```
myDocument.toObject();
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myDocument);
```

These will work, but in my opinion they just hide the problem. The real issue is that Mongoose is smarter than we realized and is enforcing your schema, as it should.

Comment: Be careful!... you will lose numbers, etc.

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myDocument);` this lead to performance problems. use `myDocument.toObject()`

Comment: @Maxwells.c, could you clarify your comment? I'm not recommending either of those approaches (those are actually recommended by the above answers), but saying they will technically work. My rec is to stick to your schema.

Comment: @misterfancypants using JSON to clone an objects doesn't have good performance because it will process to stringify the object and then parse the string to create another object. On an big project with lots of data this can slow down the application.

the toObject method of mongoose document removes all the mongoose classes and methods, leading to an pure JS object. this also isn't perfect because it will take processing.

The best solution if you doesn't want the mongoose document is to pass an argument to the query (i don't remember the tag) and it will return an array of pure objects.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the [lean()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) method, e.g. `const users = await Users.find().lean().exec()`

From the mongoose documentation:

> Documents returned from queries with the lean option enabled are plain
>   javascript objects, not MongooseDocuments. They have no save method,
>   getters/setters or other Mongoose magic applied

Answer (score 3):

My variant.

If schema defined with `{strict:false}`  you can simply add new property by

`recorcd.newProp = 'newvalue';`

If schema defined with `{strict:true}` you can either convert Mongoose object to object as mentioned earlier or use command

`record.set('newProp','newValue',{strict:false})`

See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-schema

Answer (score -1):

If you have loaded this object into `records`, both `records.Name = "test"` or `records['Name'] = "test"` will work. You have either not loaded the object correctly, or are inserting an undefined value into it.

To test: add `console.log(records.userId)`, this should print 'test' to the terminal.

Also add `console.log(name)`. If you get `ReferenceError: name is not defined`, you obviously cannot do: `records.Name = name`

Comment: Thanks for the reply

I see that console.log(records.Name) is correctly logging the value, but console.log(util.inspect(records)) doesn't have the 'Name' field, any idea why ?

Comment: @Prats: Try `console.log(util.inspect(records, 1))`. If it still gives the same, I would have to see your entire script to understand what is wrong.