# How to add an extra element in every nested array of a MongoDB object?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, object

I have a MongoDB object like this:

```
[ 
   { poster_ip: '127.0.0.1',
    post_body: 'example',
    _id: 54fc1f7808bac08f6d25f24b,
    __v: 0 },

  { poster_ip: '127.0.0.1',
    post_body: 'example',
    _id: 54fc1f7808bac08f6d25f24a,
    __v: 0 } 
]
```

how can i add an extra element to every nested array so it would be like this:

```
[ 
   { poster_ip: '127.0.0.1',
    post_body: 'example',
    _id: 54fc1f7808bac08f6d25f24a,
    __v: 0,
    newName: NewValue },

  { poster_ip: '127.0.0.1',
    post_body: 'example',
    _id: 54fc1f7808bac08f6d25f24b,
    __v: 0,
    newName: NewValue },
]
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
for(var i=0; i<JSONobject.length; i++){
    JSONobject[i].newName= NewValue;
}
```

I'm using node.js, the object is the result i get from a mongodb query.

Here is the function:

```
exports.Posts = function(UserID, PostID, callback) {

                Post.find( { post: PostID } , function(err, results) {

                var r = results.toObject(); //here i get error 'has no method toObject'

                for (var i=0; i<r.length; i++){
                    r[i].newName = "NewValue";
                }

                console.log(r);
                    //i don't see any changes here with console.log

                    return callback(null, results);
                });
}
```

**EDIT:**

After a little more research i found out that the returned Mongoose Document isn't a JSON object, so i'm trying now to convert it to an object.

Comment: Iterating based on `JSONobject.length` and changing `results[i]`?

Comment: There are serious semantic problems making it hard to follow you. Is `JSONobject` a Javascript array ? Is it the literal you first write in your question ? Then what's `results` ?

Comment: The `for` loop you posted looks fine. What makes you think it didn't work?

Comment: @Pointy it didn't work because i checked the results after the loop.

Comment: @dystroy oh, sorry for that, the previous 'results' is the JSON object. I believe that is a javascript array, correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: [Here is your code in a JSFiddle, and it works.](http://jsfiddle.net/rjnjvqkr/)

Comment: Is it possible that you're trying to modify the object without waiting for the MongoDB query to finish?

Comment: Show the code in it's full context so people don't have to guess

Comment: @Pointy I don't think so because i'm using the callback function, wait a minute, I'll check it again

Comment: @Pointy I forgot to mention that mongoose object IDs also exist in my object, I believe that they cause the problem.

Comment: Are you sure `results` is a real array? Can you add this somewhere `console.log(Array.isArray(results))`?

Comment: @SecondRikudo ok, i'll do it right now and post back.

Comment: @SecondRikudo It returned true, I really don't know what goes wrong. But i'll find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer!!

We need to tell Mongoose that all we need is a plain JavaScript version of the returned `results` by using `lean()` in the query chain.

That way Mongoose skips the step of creating the full model instance and we directly get a `results` we can modify

Like this:

```
exports.Posts = function(UserID, PostID, callback) {

                Post.find( { post: PostID } , function(err, results) {


                        for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++){
                            results[i].newName = "NewValue";
                        }

                        console.log(results);

                        return callback(null, results);

                }).lean();
}
```

Comment: can you believe this.... this was just what I was looking for. JS/Mongo can behave so strange...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why a `for` loop would fail here, because it seems fine to me. But try this:

```
results = results.map(function(item) {
    item.newName = "NewValue";
    return item;
});
```

This would create a new array where each original item is appended with the new value.

(As a rule of thumb, using `.forEach()`, `.map()`, `.filter()`, `.reduce()`, `.every()` and `.some()`  is almost always superior to `for` when looping over an array)

Comment: Sorry, didn't work either. I'm starting to believe that my object isn't a JSON object.

Comment: The `for` loop is indeed fine, something else is wrong. Maybe a stupid mistake of mine, i don't know, i'll do my best to find out.

Comment: the `console.log( Object.prototype.toString.call(results) );` returns `object Array`

Comment: It's possible that the array is an actual array, but the objects are not plain objects. But in that case, it's impossible to answer without a proper reproducible test case.

Comment: however, if i do this `results.newName = "NewValue";` it works but it adds an element outside of the previous arrays.

Comment: I found something, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16377686/2335593 the only problem is that in my case it prints `has no method 'toObject'`