# Add element to array in object in an object array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, push, element

```
"ID": 254252324242423
"objList" : [{
    "Date":3-6-2013,
    "Times": ["16:34-17:54", "18:00-19:00"]
},{
    "Date":3-7-2013,
    "Times": ["16:34-17:54", "18:23-19:00"]
},{
    "Date":3-8-2013,
    "Times": ["16:34-17:54", "18:30-20:00"]
}]
```

I don't know how to add an element to the array of an object from the list with a specific date.

Comment: see similar question [Insert element into nested arrays in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36113069/insert-element-into-nested-arrays-in-mongodb)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add an extra element in every nested array of a MongoDB object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917038/how-to-add-an-extra-element-in-every-nested-array-of-a-mongodb-object)

Answer (score 1):

this is a way i have found
Two possibilities here:

Since you don't have an unique identifier for the comments, the only way to update an specific item on the comments array is to explicitly indicate the index you are updating, like this:

```
db.documents.update(
  { _id: "iL9hL2hLauoSimtkM"},
  { $push: { "comments.0.likes": "userID3" }}
);
```

If you add an unique identifier for the comments, you can search it and update the matched item, without worrying with the index:

```
db.documents.update(
  { _id: "iL9hL2hLauoSimtkM", "comments._id": "id1"},
  { $push: { "comments.$.likes": "userID3" }}
);
```